# Deploy REST service without access to IIS

Tags: c#, .net, rest, iis, httphandler

I have developed a .NET REST web service in C#. While I have plenty of C# experience, I unfortunately do not have much understanding in deploying such a service in a web hosting environment.

Due to the environment, I do NOT have access to IIS.

The advice I have been provided with by the support services of the hosting provider is as follows:

1. Create a subdomain of the main domain to achieve a dedicated application pool (this a requirement of the host provider)
2. Create a Bin folder to hold my compiled libraries of source code
3. Add the following to the Web.Config file:

> ```
>  <system.web>
>     <httpHandlers>
>         <add type="ReportRESTWebService.Service, ReportRESTWebService" verb="*" path="report" />
>     </httpHandlers>
> </system.web>
> <system.webServer>
>     <handlers>
>         <add name="report" path="report" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
>     </handlers>
>     <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
> </system.webServer>
> ```

The above would have the effect of creating a handler mapping for the report resource on all HTTP verbs and forwarding any HTTP traffic on that resource to my ReportRESTWebService.dll for handling.

The point I am unclear on is whether the above will be satisfactory and how do I test whether the advice I am given is correct. I know that I have the site running locally but I have access to IIS so I have control over the configuration.

Hopefully somebody can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem, after a day of exhaustive testing, that the steps I had taken (detailed in the question) would be satisfactory.

One point to watch out for is the matching Managed Pipeline Mode for your application pool. Failure to match this up correctly with your Web.Config will result in pain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wcf Rest,then you can probably consider hosting it as as windows service 
or self hosted service.
`Windows Service`
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/juveriak/archive/2009/03/15/rest-endpoint-hosted-in-a-wcf-windows-service.aspx

`Self hosted Service`
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/self-hosted-wcf-rest-service-or-hosting-wcf-rest-service-in-console-application/

Comment: Sorry but it is not a WCF service